# Search through multiple dataframes to find words in R

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes (example below) in my global environment and want to search through all of them for keywords.

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c("laptop","fridge","basket"))
df2<-data.frame(col1=c("TV","Radio","Car"))
df3<-data.frame(column1=c("TV","Candle","laptop"))
```

In this example, is there a way to query all the dataframes and return a list of dataframes where TV is listed?

Comment: One could always use `ls()` to find object names, check with `is.data.frame`, then `sapply(get(.), ...)`. Is there a reason you have them as separate frames instead of a list of multiple frames? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the code below

```
subset(
  lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d")),
  sapply(lst, function(v) any(v == "TV")),
)
```

which gives

```
$df2
   col1
1    TV
2 Radio
3   Car

$df3
  column1
1      TV
2  Candle
3  laptop
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  It finds all of the elements in your workspace and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` for the data frames and `NA` for things that aren't data frames.

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c("laptop","fridge","basket"))
df2<-data.frame(col1=c("TV","Radio","Car"))
df3<-data.frame(column1=c("TV","Candle","laptop"))
df4 <- 3

elems <- ls()
sapply(elems, function(x){
  tmp <- eval(parse(text = x))
  if(inherits(tmp, "data.frame")){
    length(sapply(1:ncol(tmp), function(i)grep("TV", tmp[[i]]))[[1]]) > 0
  }else{
    NA
  }
})

#   df1   df2   df3   df4 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Filter` :

```
Filter(function(x) any(x == 'TV'), mget(ls(pattern = 'df\\d+')))

#$df2
#   col1
#1    TV
#2 Radio
#3   Car

#$df3
#  column1
#1      TV
#2  Candle
#3  laptop
```

To get the names of dataframes :

```
names(Filter(function(x) any(x == 'TV'), mget(ls(pattern = 'df\\d+'))))
#[1] "df2" "df3"
```